# C# StringBuilder : i can't set a specific Microsoft Word line feed

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, ms-word, linefeed

I have created a template in word, basically, a word document with some [Something] to be replaced in a C# console application, and i'm trying to set a spécific character as a line feed.

Indeed, in word, according of the line feed character you are using, it will allow or not the page break into a table cell.

To be very clear, when you have clicked the display all char button, you can see all the special characters.

The one i want to add is this one : [good linefeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XvWW.png) but, i tried all unicode character i found on wikipedia and i always have this kind of linefeed [bad return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0cc3.png)

I use this librairy to manipulate the docx document : github.com/WordDocX/DocX

And this is the code i have used in the "Examples" project of the DocX github librairy :

```
private static void ModifyTemplate()
{
// Loading the template
using (DocX document = DocX.Load("D:\\DocX-master\\Examples\\docs\\Template.docx"))
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder("");

    sb.Clear();
    sb.AppendLine("bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla.");
    //Testing all the unicode codes i found here : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline
    sb.Append("u000D\u000D").Append("u000A\u000A").Append("u0085\u0085").Append("u000B\u000B").Append("u000C\u000C").Append("u2028\u2028").Append("u2029\u2029");
    sb.AppendLine("AppendLine");

    document.ReplaceText("[test]", sb.ToString());
    //Testing with a different encoding
    String test = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sb.ToString()));
    document.ReplaceText("[test]", test);

    #region Saving the modified template on the disk

    // Save all changes to this document.
    document.SaveAs(@"docs\Result.docx");

    #endregion

}// Release this document from memory.
```

}

My word template is basically a new docx with the texte [Test] and [Test2] inside

The result with this code :

Sorry i can't post images... so i can't show you the final result... but trust me, none of this unicode seems to produce the right result

To conclude, no matter what unicode code i use, it is impossible to have the good return char

What unicode code i should use? Or what encoding trick should i use to have the linefeed char i seek ?

Comment: I thought in word now they used mainly html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you need to use "`InsertParagraph`"

```
Paragraph p1 = document.InsertParagraph();
p1.Append("New Para 1");

Paragraph p2 = document.InsertParagraph();
p2.Append("New Para 2");

Paragraph p3 = document.InsertParagraph();
p3.Append("New Para 3");
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Indeed! I just foud where the difference is coming from : when you add a linefeed with code, it will add it INSIDE a cell (AKA a specific OpenXml bloc), when you add a line with Word, it will add a whole new XML bloc (with, for instance, the font, the size, the culture info... etc). That's why it is impossible to do it via a simple unicode char. But thanx to the the InsertParagraph method it should be possible and solve my problem. Thx a lot

Comment: Glad that you were able to solve the issue. Why don't you mark the answer as accepted, if it worked?

Comment: I would like to... how do you do that ?

Comment: Ok i found it :) Thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

Thx to Aruk tip, i managed to solve this issue.

By using InsertParagraph on the specific cell i want, i can have the wanted linefeed, the one Word can understand and use.

One issue is remaining, i am losing the style of my former tag [something], but this shouldn't be too much of an issue to solve

Thx a lot